# Select column value with min value partition by another column but NOT repeat ranking

Tags: mysql, sql, rank

I am looking to fetch the eqp based on min distance by contract, but if an eqp is taken by a contract then it shouldn't be considered.

Table: T1

| id | contract | eqp | distance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 123 | A | 2 |
| 2 | 123 | B | 5 |
| 3 | 123 | C | 20 |
| 4 | 124 | A | 2 |
| 5 | 124 | B | 7 |
| 6 | 124 | C | 11 |

I used rank and it gives me same rank for two different contract but I would not want to use the rank for a prior record already taken.

```
SELECT
id,contract,eqp,rk
FROM
(
SELECT id,contract,eqp,
RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY contract ORDER BY distance) AS rk
FROM t1
) a
WHERE rk=1
```

What I get is below,

| id | contract | eqp | distance | rk |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 123 | A | 2 | 1 |
| 4 | 124 | A | 2 | 1 |

Expected Output:

| id | contract | eqp | distance | rk |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 123 | A | 2 | 1 |
| 5 | 124 | B | 7 | 1 |

Comment: each eqp appears once only in the result set, what happens if number of contract is more than the number of eqp? or there is assumption it won't happen?

Comment: Why rows 1 and 5, and not 4 and 2? What is the criteria?

Comment: Akinas question is very important. SQL is set based. There is no inherent processing order; the rows 1 and 4 are found at the same time. But you want a particular processing order. You want to find the row for contract 123 first and then look for the row for contract 124. What makes you decide for this order? Is it because the contract number 123 is smaller than 124? Or because contract 123 has the lowest ID in the table? Or because you want to start with the contract that has the lowest distance in the table and in case of a tie you pick one contract arbitrarily? Or is there some other rule?

Comment: Then, what do you want to happen when we run out of eqps? Let's say we have contracts 123, 124, 125, and 126, but only have eqps A, B, and C. What to do with the last contract? Dismiss it from the results? Show the contract number without an ID, eqp, distance and rk? Anything else?

Comment: Well, I don't know if I've added anything essential here. After all I've just elaborated what ProGu and Akina already asked :-) As to the solution: This is an iterative process. You need a stored procedure or a recursive query for this.

Answer (score 1):

The task is iterative. It cannot be solved by single query.

Possible solution:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE proc ()
BEGIN
CREATE TABLE tmp LIKE t1;
REPEAT
    INSERT INTO tmp
    SELECT t1.*
    FROM t1
    LEFT JOIN tmp t2 ON t1.contract = t2.contract   -- for huge table
    LEFT JOIN tmp t3 ON t1.eqp = t3.eqp             -- use NOT EXISTS
    WHERE t2.id IS NULL
      AND t3.id IS NULL
    ORDER BY distance LIMIT 1;     -- adjust to needed priority
UNTIL NOT ROW_COUNT() END REPEAT;
SELECT * FROM tmp;
DROP TABLE tmp;
END
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c9563e1d2e9884dc607a52f10ff401bb